# Managing the printer

Tags: cups

We implemented CUP to deal with batch jobs (e.g. 500 PDF files per batch) printed on a network printer.

Under the old way of printing (Microsoft print spooler) the user could select to "print and hold". On entering a code on the printer, the user could then enter his unique code which would then start the printing. We now implemented batch printing  using CUPS. CUPS now prints directly to the printer but also we run into memory problems on the printer. Can CUPS be configured to:
 1. "Print & hold"
 2. ensure that CUPS deals with the printer within it's memory confines

Answer (score 0):

It depends. This is something that would need to be supported by the driver of the printer in question. If yours does support it, it will be listed in the printer options. To check whether that is the case, you can use `lpoptions -l` to get a list of the available options of your printer.

If it does support it, you can use the -o command-line option to `lpr` to set the option; many GUI applications w will also allow you to set such options in their printing dialog box.

Finally, since such features are typically things that are only available if certain options have been installed, you may have to tell cups that the optional feature is in fact installed. You can do this by way of cups' management interface, which you can access by pointing a web browse to `localhost:631` on the machine running cups.